# Opencv CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT return negative larg number

Tags: c++, opencv

VideoCapture capture(captureFileName);
I am using Opencv 3.3.1. 
I am using the following cod.

```
    if (!capture.isOpened()) {
        throw "Error when reading file";
    }

    cout << "capture.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)"
            << capture.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) << endl;
    cout << "capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)" << capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
            << endl;
```

When the video size is around 30MB, capture.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) return value around 16632. However, when the video size is around 150MB, capture.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) return value around -2.30584e+14.

The rest of the code cannot run as well (after that line). Did anyone run large video with opencv before?

---

update:

I realized the problem is in the source video. I download the stream with vlc and it did not stop recording properly and a 1 minute video is more than 100mb(frames after 30mb are corrupted). VideoCapture works well on other video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't depend on the video size. The property will be correctly returned for videos with much larger size than 150 MB.

If your two videos are identical in container and video codec, most likely your second video is corrupted somehow. This can happen e.g. by not cleanly aborting while writing the video file. You could try to fix this by re-encoding (e.g. with ffmpeg) if you absolutely need the frame count.

Otherwise just ignore the frame count and keep grabbing frames until you reach the end of the video, which may still work correctly, even if you don't have a frame count.

Comment: I realized my problem is when I use vlc to save udp stream video, the file became incredibly large. It is a 9 minutes video but when I put the video in video editor, it showed 23566 days: 9hours... vlc probably is the problem.